# Count of stored procedures generated using SSMS "Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard" differs

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I have generated stored procedures using SSMS wizard as shown below. There is an option to save each object as a single file. The issue is when I counted procedures using  SELECT count(*) FROM sys.procedures it differs from number files generated.

[image: SSMS generate scripts]

[image: Single file per object]

Answer (score 0):

There are 7 procedure under  "system stored procedures" folder starting with dbo. extension.  These will be counted  when we run the query(SELECT count(*) FROM sys.procedures) for count of procs, but won't be part generated script.

sp_alterdiagram
sp_creatediagram
sp_dropdiagram
sp_helpdiagramdefinition
sp_helpdiagrams
sp_renamediagram
sp_upgraddiagrams